# Using images in flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to make a moviepage using flexbox. I have three images in one flexbox, but I can't get them to come on top of each other, they will only place next to each other. Any tips? And btw, I am not making the page responsive yet.

**CSS**

```
/*FLEXBOKS*/

.flex-container{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    margin: 100px;

}


.flex-item1{
    order: <integer>;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    flex-basis: auto;
    align-self: stretch;
    background-color: #B0B0B0;

}

.flex-item2{
    order: <integer>;
    flex-grow: 2; 
    flex-shrink: 1; 
    flex-basis: auto;
    align-self: baseline;
    background-color: #B0B0B0;
}



.flex-item3{
    order: <integer>;
    flex-grow: 2; 
    flex-shrink: 1;
    flex-basis: auto;
    align-self: baseline;
    background-color: #B0B0B0;

}

.flex-item4{

    order: <integer>;
    flex-grow: 2; 
    flex-shrink: 1;
    flex-basis: auto;
    align-self: baseline;
    background-color: orange;

}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="flex-container">


<div class="flex-item1">
<h2>NEW MOVIES</h2>
<img src="The_Intouchables_3.jpg" width="200" height="250"> 
<img src="The_Lunchbox_1.jpg" width="200" height="250"> 
<img src="montypythonandtheholygrail_1.jpg" width="200" height="250">
</div>



<div class="flex-item2">LAST RENTED</div>


<div class="flex-item3">RECOMMENDATIONS</div>


<div class="flex-item4">RULES</div>



</div>
```

Comment: Try using flex direction: column on parent container

Answer (score 2):

Set to the flex container the css rule

```
flex-direction: column;
```

Comment: that worked! But any tips on how to center the images in my flexbox?

Comment: vertically or horizontally? try to use justify-content: center; and align-items: center; always in the container box

Answer (score 1):

You can use following CSS

```
.flex-container{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    margin: 100px;
}
```